I have a question about Hartshorne Chapter2 Lemma 4.5
Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a quasi-compact morphism of scheme. Then the subset $f(X)$ of $Y$ is closed if and only if it is stable under specialization.
Show that if $f(X)$ is stable under specialization, then it is closed.
First question.
Hartshorne says clearly we may assume that $X$ and $Y$ are both reduced, and that $f(X)^{-} = Y$(replace $Y$ by the reduced induced structure on $f(X)^{-}$).
I cannot understand this sentence. Why $X,Y$ reduced?
Second question.
We may assume that $Y$ is affine. Let $y \in Y$ be a point, then we wish to show that $y \in f(X)$. Since $f$ is quasi-compact, $X$ will be a finite union of open affines $X_i$. And for some $i$,  $y \in f(X_i)^{-}$. Let $Y_i = f(X_i)^{-}$ with reduced induced structure. Then $Y_i$ is also affine, and we will consider the dominant morphism $X_i \rightarrow Y_i$ of reduced affine schemes.
I cannot understand last sentence. Why $Y_i$ is affine.

The question is of underlying topological space, and the induced map between reduced schemes is same on underlying topological spaces.

For the second question, any closed subscheme of an affine scheme is affine.

@okaberintarou those look like an answer to me - please consider recording them as such below.

The assertion of lemma 4.5 is about underlying topological spaces. $f$ induces a map $g: X_{\text{red}}\to Y_{\text{red}}$ between the reduced schemes. This map is same to $f$ on underlying topological spaces (so again quasi-compact); see exercise 2.3 in same chapter. So $f(X)$ is closed or closed under specialization if and only if $g(X_{\text{red}})$ does, addressing your first question. For the second question, $Y_i$ is the closed subscheme of $Y$ which we assumed to be affine, so affine; you may refer to exercise 3.11 of same chapter, or corollary 5.10.
